# How to obtain all URLs from an external page?

Tags: javascript, php

My goal is to obtain all URLs from [this page](https://www.coop.ch/de/aktionen/wochenaktionen/aktionen-fleisch-fisch/c/m_1380?q=%3Arelevance&sort=specialOffers&pageSize=10000&page=1).

This is what I have tried:

```php
<?php
$url = 'https://www.coop.ch/de/aktionen/wochenaktionen/aktionen-fleisch-fisch/c/m_1380?q=' . urlencode(':relevance') . '&sort=specialOffers&pageSize=10000&page=1';

$html = file_get_contents($url);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($links as $index => $link) {
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
    echo "$href <br>";
}
```

That gives me some of the URLs but not all of them. Most likely it is because some of the contents are dynamic.

I also tried it with the Fetch API of JavaScript, but this will not work because of CORS Policy.

How do I get the URLs?

### Update

The comment from [KIKO Software](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3986005/kiko-software) resolved this issue. But I would also like to obtain the URLs from [this website](https://www.migros.ch/de/offers/home?context=instore&gad=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjw2eilBhCCARIsAG0Pf8tJLOLm9ncwTQe0b-h2aWV2GIr7iQeEg8cAO8GK6eCl5ggnyLxBnPUaAlKWEALw_wcB). This makes it a bit more difficult since I don't even see the URLs in the source code. Probably because this website is based on Angular. Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: I think the URL's you're interested in are located in a script element that is used as data block and contains [JSON-LD](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/). Now I agree that you would normally use DOMDocument to parse HTML, but perhaps here a simply string extraction would do the job. Get the JSON data after `<!-- ItemList schema -->` and parse that.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware you're a genius! That helped me a lot. Thank you! Do you also see a way to get the URLs from the page https://www.migros.ch/de/offers/home?context=instore&gad=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjw2eilBhCCARIsAG0Pf8tJLOLm9ncwTQe0b-h2aWV2GIr7iQeEg8cAO8GK6eCl5ggnyLxBnPUaAlKWEALw_wcB ? Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything in the source code.

Comment: Migros is a dynamic website, loading its content with a 108 separate requests. It loads the product information from a JSON endpoint with the URL https://www.migros.ch/product-display/public/v3/product-cards, but you need to supply the uids which come from another file. So, it's doable, but requires a bit of extra effort. I don't actually inspect the HTML source code of the site to find these URLs, I use [the browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools). Perhaps that tip can make life easier for you?

Comment: Note: If sites want to stop you scraping their content, they can quite easily do that. In other words, there's never a guarantee that scraping will be possible, and successful in the long term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the URL's you're interested in are located in a script element that is used as data block and contains [JSON-LD](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/).

Now I agree that you would normally use DOMDocument to parse HTML, but perhaps here a simply string extraction would do the job.

Here is my attempt:

```
$url  = 'https://www.coop.ch/de/aktionen/wochenaktionen/aktionen-fleisch-fisch/c/m_1380?q=' . urlencode(':relevance') . '&sort=specialOffers&pageSize=10000&page=1';
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$json = str_before('</script>',
                   str_after(' <script type="application/ld+json">',
                   str_after('<!-- ItemList schema -->',
                             $html)));
$data = json_decode($json);
foreach ($data->itemListElement as $item) {
    echo $item->url .'<br>';
}
```

This returns:

```
https://www.coop.ch:443/lebensmittel/fleisch-fisch/abgepackter-fisch/geraeucherter-fisch/labeyrie-lachsfilet-geraeuchert/p/4922140
https://www.coop.ch:443/lebensmittel/fleisch-fisch/abgepacktes-frischfleisch/schwein/naturafarm-schweins-hals-koteletten-4-stueck/p/5907238
https://www.coop.ch:443/lebensmittel/fleisch-fisch/abgepacktes-frischfleisch/schwein/schweinehals-tessinerbraten-ca/p/6451707
https://www.coop.ch:443/lebensmittel/fleisch-fisch/abgepacktes-frischfleisch/schwein/schweins-hals-tessinerbraten-ca/p/6621610
https://www.coop.ch:443/lebensmittel/fleisch-fisch/abgepackter-fisch/abgepackter-frischfisch/lachsfilet-asc-mariniert-mit-haut-ca/p/7158054
https://www.coop.ch:443/lebensmittel/fleisch-fisch/charcuterie-wurstwaren/wuerste/bratwuerste-cervelas/bell-stgaller-olma-bratwurst-3x2-stueck/p/5959878
https://www.coop.ch:443/lebensmittel/fleisch-fisch/abgepackter-fisch/abgepackter-frischfisch/dorade-royale-asc-3-stueck/p/7156874
https://www.coop.ch:443/lebensmittel/fleisch-fisch/abgepacktes-frischfleisch/schwein/naturafarm-schweins-koteletten-3-stueck/p/5907239
https://www.coop.ch:443/lebensmittel/fleisch-fisch/abgepackter-fisch/krustentiere-muscheln/crevetten-roh-asc/p/6608729
and so on.....
```

I use two functions I already had:

```
function str_before($needle, $haystack)
{
    $pos = mb_strpos($haystack, $needle);
    return ($pos !== FALSE) ? mb_substr($haystack, 0, $pos) : $haystack;
}

function str_after($needle, $haystack)
{
    $pos = mb_strpos($haystack, $needle);
    return ($pos !== FALSE) ? mb_substr($haystack, $pos + mb_strlen($needle)) : $haystack;
}
```

So this does work. Notice that I don't do any error checking at all, you have to incorporate that yourself if you want to. I'm also surprised a simple `file_get_contents($url)` works, normally you would have to use [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) and fake some headers.

And finally a gentle warning about scraping websites: Be kind to the website. Don't scrape many pages at the highest speed you can. [Don't abuse the web.](https://towardsdatascience.com/ethics-in-web-scraping-b96b18136f01)